# Error while trying to add geometry types to my postgis connection

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, postgis

I have create a project with eclipse and added the postgis-jdbc-2.1.7.jar , postgresql-9.4.1208.jre6.jar to my class path.

Then I tried the example from the postgis documentation [see example](http://postgis.net/docs/ch06.html#idp70857904) in order to connect to the db.

The following lines produce an error:

```
 /* 
* Add the geometry types to the connection. Note that you 
* must cast the connection to the pgsql-specific connection 
* implementation before calling the addDataType() method. 
*/
   ((org.postgresql.PGConnection)conn).addDataType("geometry",Class.forName("org.postgis.PGgeometry"));
   ((org.postgresql.PGConnection)conn).addDataType("box3d",Class.forName("org.postgis.PGbox3d"));
```

The error is the following:

The method addDataType in the type connection is not applicable for the arguments

Has anyone else faced the same error?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Is this a run-time error? Perhaps Class.forName() is returning null. Try making a static reference to the class by replacing the call to "Class.forName()" with "org.postgis.PGgeometry.class" which will fail at compile time instead of run time if your classpath is off.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). I'm flagging this post for deletion.